# What is the behavior of `getopts` when it meets `--`?

Tags: bash, getopts

By convention `--` signals that there is no more options after it. 
It seems to me that when using `getopts` with `case` clause, `-)` pattern subclause doesn't match `--`. So what is the behavior of `getopts` when it meets `--`?  Does it treat `--` as an option, a nonoption argument, or neither? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The behaviour is that it stops parsing the command line and leaves the rest of the arguments as is. The `--` itself is removed (or rather `$OPTIND` will indicate that it was processed but `$opt` in the code below will never be `-`, and if you `shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"` as one usually does, you'll never see it).

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts 'a:b:' opt; do
    case "$opt" in
        a)  printf 'Got a: "%s"\n' "$OPTARG" ;;
        b)  printf 'Got b: "%s"\n' "$OPTARG" ;;
        *)  echo 'error' >&2
            exit 1
    esac
done

shift "$(( OPTIND - 1 ))"

printf 'Other argument: "%s"\n' "$@"
```

Running it:

```
$ bash script.sh -a hello -- -b world
Got a: "hello"
Other argument: "-b"
Other argument: "world"
```

As you can see, the `-b world` bit of the command line was not processed by `getopts`.

It stops parsing the command line at `--` or at the first non-option argument:

```
$ bash script.sh something -a hello -- -b world
Other argument: "something"
Other argument: "-a"
Other argument: "hello"
Other argument: "--"
Other argument: "-b"
Other argument: "world"
```

In this case, `--` was *not* "removed" since `getopts` never got that far.